# How can you simulate the effect of a solvent on a polymer in an MD simulation?

Tags: computational-chemistry, polymers, solvents, molecular-dynamics

I'm doing a molecular dynamics simulation of polymer melts and I want to include the effect of a good/bad solvent on the melt. How can this be done?

My simulation models polymers using a bead-spring model and the interactions forces are Lennard-Jones for pair interactions and FENE for bonding forces.

Edit:

FENE stands for Finite Extensible Nonlinear Elastic. It's a log based elastic force.
The potential function used, Lennard Jones + FENE is described here (http://lammps.sandia.gov/doc/bond_fene.html)

Comment: What's FENE? Can you provide a link or reference?

Answer (score 1):

You have generally two choices a) implicit and b) explicit solvent. Presumably, you don't have good interaction parameters for explicit solvent, since you are likely doing a generic polymer melt.

There are a variety of solvation models; [LAMMPS](http://lammps.sandia.gov/doc/pair_coul_diel.html), for instance, implements a dielectric pair style for which you can attenuate the dielectric constant of your solvent (and a few other things). Other popular approximations are [generalized Born models](http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/namd/2.10b1/ug/node28.html).

[This paper](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ma901632c) uses GROMACS to simulate poly(styrene sulfonate) and poly(allylamine hydrochloride) in explicit and implicit solvent, as an example from the literature.